# How to create a link to open the Steam Chat for a specific friend user on a Google Chrome tab?

Tags: javascript

I tried to create a link to open Steam Chat on Google Chrome but the URL is always "https://steamcommunity.com/chat". I don't know how to open a specific friend user tab to chat with directly on a specific chat tab. There is a similar function in the "Augmented Steam" Google extension but it only opens a separate customed(?) window not a tab in the same Chrome window.

I'm writing a Javascript script for Tampermonkey on Google Chrome.

[EDIT]:

1. I want to open a specific Steam chat user tab on the URL "https://steamcommunity.com/chat" in **the same Chrome window**.
2. I already create a Steam chat link on everyone's Steam profile page.
3. This is my code:

```
<span>
  <a href='https://steamcommunity.com/chat' class='btn_profile_action btn_medium'>
  Steam Chat
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to open steamcommunity.com  and access this code as a link or simply copy and paste in your steamcommunity.com tab
javascript:OpenFriendChat( friend_userid, 280740398 );

Comment: What did you mean?  Like this?!  `<a href="javascript:OpenFriendChat('friend_userid, 280740398)">Chat</a>`
 But, I have seen these codes on the Steam profile page before.  Doesn't it only open the Steam client Chat window?  What's the code to open the Steam Chat tab for a specific user on Google Chrome?

Comment: If you open the steamcommunity.com url and then copy and paste the javascript code I wrote above and replace friend_userid for the id of a specific user it actually opens the steam chat tab for that specific user. Im guessing you are creating a google chrome plugin?

Comment: Hi, 1) Like I said in the question, I'm writing a Tampermonkey script on Google Chrome. 2) Where should I put this code in my codes exactly? I already create a Chat link on everyone's Steam profile.  But it only opens the general Steam Chat tab(https://steamcommunity.com/chat), not for a specific user. 3) I tried to enter this code in the console on "steamcommunity.com" on Chrome but it works as the Augmented Steam extension did, open a separate chat window that can't be put into the main Chrome window.